# Meaning of triangle with eye in "Life Is Strange"

Tags: life-is-strange

I am just after the first episode of *Life is Strange*. Few times I noticed a triangle with an eye. For example: in school bathroom, on wall near school, in Chloe car and Chloe room. What does this symbol mean in this game and why is it in it?

[image: Strange symbol]

Comment: A screenshot would help your post a lot.  See if you can get one.

Comment: Presumably OP means the Illuminati Pyramid.

Comment: It roughly translates to: *"Reality's an illusion, the universe is a hologram, buy gold!"*

Comment: The Illuminati must be doing a better job recently if people no longer recognize their symbol.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The symbol is the [eye of providence](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence).

The symbol is not unique to Life is Strange. It exists in the real world, originally as a Christian symbol. In modern times it is often linked with conspracies and secret societies, largely because of its appearance in US government symbols (most notably on the $1 bill).

Whether it represents divine guidance, conspiracies, or if it's just [Bill Cipher](http://gravityfalls.wikia.com/wiki/Bill_Cipher) is something  only the devs know and is unfortunately off-topic here.

Comment: Upvote just for Bill Cipher.

Comment: Illuminati confirmed

Comment: "unfortunately off-topic here" NICE TRY ILLUMINATI